# How to pass string to a function inside a directive in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the templating function for the custom directive which I have created.
The string **str** passed to the function `obtainDynamicField(str)` is coming as undefined. Also **str** is a **string** and not a **variable**.

```
 function getTemplate() {
            return

'           <td>' +
            '       <div class="inner">' +
            '                   <input type="text" ' +
            '                               class="form-control" ' +
            '                               data-dynamic-field="obtainDynamicField(str)"'+
            '                               data-ng-model="formdata.product" >' +
            '                           </input>' +
            '                       </div>' +
            '           </td>' +
```

I am struggling for the past 2-3 hours in this. I think I need to escape out the **str** which I am unable to think so far on how to achieve it. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood the question, but you need to pass a string?

So something like this? `'data-dynamic-field="obtainDynamicField(\'str\')"'`?

Comment: @rpadovani: Impressive, captivating. Give it as an answer and I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to escape the `'` around the string:

`'data-dynamic-field="obtainDynamicField(\'str\')"'`